# skew, but vertical?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word describing a center-mass shift, similar to **skew** (left/right) but implying the center-mass is shifting vertically (up/down).

The use is for a UI that distorts a 2D shape. I am using skew for the x-axis and need a similar but unambiguous word for the y-axis (vertical).

Comment: Nothing wrong with ***skewed upward***

Comment: thank you @Jim. I'm using skew for x-axis, and need another word for y-axis. I have edited the question.

Comment: *Skew* by itself does not specify a direction. As such, it's bound to be ambiguous all by itself no matter what other word you choose to complement it. You can try adopting terms from some unrelated domain (like I dunno, *yaw, pitch,* and *roll*), but I think for the average user that will work even worse. So I would probably opt for clearly specifying the axis right in the name. X skew and Y skew. Or X distortion and Y distortion.

Comment: Are you distorting or translating?  I would not use “Skew” for a distortion in either direction. But if you are truly just moving the center of mass, then that’s a translation not a distortion and skew is applicable to either axis.  Maybe you could displace vertically and shift horizontally.

Comment: *X skew* and *Y skew*. Don’t increase the cognitive burden on the user by using a completely different word for a similar concept.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider sticking to paradigms / nomenclature that is already commonly used in computer graphics (programming, UI frameworks, design software, etc.)

Skew, also known as shear, is a transformation that stretches the (2D) coordinate space in a non-uniform manner. Axis can be either X or Y.

Examples:

- Windows programming: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.skewtransform
- iOS/Mac programming: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758893/skew-uiview-without-giving-perspective-and-keeping-heigh-and-width
- Photoshop skewing both along both X and Y: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TK3aM2ExxHo

Answer (score 1):

**azimuth** may be better for "Left / Right" than skew.
**Elevation** might work for "Up / down"...